# Nesting <pre> and </pre> tags

Tags: html, dom

Ok, so weird one. Is it possible to escape a `</pre>` tag in a `<pre>` block?

I have a project wiki in [Redmine](http://www.redmine.org/). It uses [Coderay](http://coderay.rubychan.de/) for syntax highlighting, like so:

```
<pre>
<code class="JavaScript">

//your JS code here

</code>
</pre>
```

I'm writing a wiki explaining to our users how to use Redmine. I need to document above... but this results in nested `<pre>` tags:

```
<pre>
<pre>
<code class="JavaScript">

//your JS code here

</code>
</pre>
</pre>
```

**Output:**

```
<pre>
<code class="[LANGUAGE NAME]">

//your JS code here

</code>
```

The last `</pre>` is missing as it closes the previous `<pre>` tag. Is there any way I can escape the `</pre>` so that it is displayed?

**Desired Ouput:**

```
<pre>
<code class="[LANGUAGE NAME]">

//your JS code here

</code>
</pre>
```

Comment: It seems that you actually do *not* want to “nest tags” but display HTML tags. If the normal method of escaping each “<” as “&lt;” does not work, you need to specify the context and environment.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela The context and environment are explained in the post. The environment is Redmine and the plugin that is displaying code is CodeRay. The rendering engine for the rest of the text is Textile. I think I've hit a limitation of what can be achieved using these tools.

Answer (score 4):

If you want `<`, `>`, `"`, and `&` characters to be rendered as text in HTML you need to use their HTML entity counterparts:

`<` becomes `&lt;`
`>` becomes `&gt;`
`"` becomes `&quot;`
`&` becomes `&amp;`

```
<pre>
    &lt;pre&gt;
        foo bar baz
    &lt;/pre&gt;
</pre>
```

In some special cases you may want `'` escaped, in which case you should use `&#39;` (or `&apos;` if you don't need to worry about old versions of IE).

Comment: Doesn't work. The moment you put a <pre> around it, the rendered leaves &lt; etc as it is and prints that to the page.

Comment: So it does! Doesn't work in Redmine - must be a redmine specific issue. It uses Textile - similar to Markdown for Github - to process text formatting.